# I can't do pagination in real-time firebase web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a mini project from a real-time database of a firebase database, but I have a problem with a lot of data. I want to show only 3 items and other items are classified as pagination.

like this

[image]

I try to follow other articles in stackoverflow But I was unsuccessful.

ref 1 : [Firebase Realtime DB pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60415659/firebase-realtime-db-pagination)

ref 2 : [How to implement pagination in Firebase using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47068832/how-to-implement-pagination-in-firebase-using-)

this's my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-elbakyan-wmwmq

What do I have to do?
thank you so much.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, you need to download and process your data ready to be added to the table. Because you wish to know how many pages of entries you have, you first must perform a shallow query for all the documents in your database.

To get this list, you would `fetch()` (with appropriate authorization if needed) the following URL:

```
https://testrealtime-191b1.firebaseio.com/project.json?shallow=true
```

This will return a list of all projects in your database:

```
{
  "-M3aofA_ZwRPwqVdAv7r" : true,
  "-M3aogPeqB6kGi5RxDY0" : true,
  "-M3aor_wyrxlbD5A6BSn" : true
  ...
}
```

You can then count the number of entries in the list using `Object.keys(data).length`. Note that this number may increase or decrease while a user is looking at the table. Be prepared to handle such cases.

Next, you should download your first page of data:

```js
function showData() {
  var PAGE_SIZE = 3;

  // TODO: Fetch page count & then update page buttons
  fetch('https://testrealtime-191b1.firebaseio.com/project.json?shallow=true')
    .then(function (response) { return response.json() })
    .then(function (projectKeysObject) {
      var projectCount = Object.keys(projectKeysObject).length;
      var pageCount = Math.ceil(projectCount / PAGE_SIZE);
      // TODO: Update UI with appropriate number of page buttons
    })
    .catch(console.error) // TODO: handle errors

  // in parallel to the above, fetch your initial page of data
  var projectsRef = firebase.database().ref("project");

  projectsRef.limitToFirst(PAGE_SIZE).once("value").then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(projectSnapshot) {
      var projectKey = projectSnapshot.key;
      var projectData = projectSnapshot.val();

      // init row
      var rowEle = table.insertRow(); // appends row

      // add data to row
      rowEle.insertCell().append(projectData.published);
      rowEle.insertCell().innerHTML = '<img src="' + projectData.img_post + '" alt=""><span class="title-post">' + projectData.title_post + '</span>';
      rowEle.insertCell().append(projectData.reward);
      rowEle.insertCell().append(projectData.quantity);
      rowEle.insertCell().append(projectData.announce);

      // add button to last column
      var btnUpdate = document.createElement("button");
      btnUpdate.textContent = "edit";
      btnUpdate.setAttribute("class", "bbbb");
      btnUpdate.setAttribute("data-id", projectKey);
      btnUpdate.setAttribute("disabled", true);
      rowEle.insertCell().append(btnUpdate);
    });
  })
  .catch(console.error); // TODO: handle errors
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, and the function for pressing for next page such as 1, 2, 3, 4 ... How to do? please ( ꒪⌓꒪)  @samthecodingman

Comment: Where I have `// TODO: Update UI`, you just need to add commands like you did for `btnUpdate`. So find the element that will contain the buttons, create and append each page's button to that element. Unfortunately StackOverflow isn't a "develop this for me service". You've got the pieces already, you just have to assemble the jigsaw puzzle - you've got this.